# Trying to create a python decorator for retrieving authentication token

Tags: python, rest, authentication, python-decorators

I've used decorators before but have never built my own. I tried reading some docs and online help on this topic but I'm kind of confused at this point.

I have a server I want to make API calls to and it requires retrieving a token to make your api calls. If your token ever expires you will get back an http 401 and you just simply need to get another token.

Right now in all of my functions I just have an If statement checking for the 401 and refreshing the token if that is the case.

But this *seems* like the appropriate case to use a decorator but I'm kind of unsure how I would go about it.

Also, please let me know if this is not a good question for this site.

Here is my code now:

```
def get_token(self) -> str:
    r = self.session.post(
        BASE_URL + "authentication/signin",
        data=dumps({"name": self.username, "password": self.password}),
        verify=False,
    )

    if not r.ok:
        raise Exception()
    elif "token" not in (response := r.json()):
        raise Exception("Token not found in response")

    return response["token"]

def get_device(self, ip: str) -> dict[str, Any]:
    data = dumps({"ipAddress": ip.strip()})

    if (
        r := self.session.post(BASE_URL + "devices/filter", data=data)
    ).status_code == 401:
        self.session.headers.update({"X-AUTH-TOKEN": self.get_token()})
        r = self.session.post(BASE_URL + "devices/filter", data=data)

    if not r.ok:
        raise Exception()
    elif "content" not in (response := r.json()):
        raise Exception()

    return response["content"][0]
```

Comment: Could you show us your current code?

Comment: Yeah that would help wouldn't it lol. I just added it to my question

Comment: I'm not sure you really need a *decorator*; rather, you need a layer of indirection around `self.session.post` that will retry a failed attempt with a new token when necessary.

Comment: this is a good question. I apologize for whoever down voted you.

Comment: @jsbueno I was wondering why my question was bad :(

Comment: No, I consider it good - and certainly a lot of people here - @chepner would not have answered it if it was not good enough, for example. But here we are all humans, with diverse opinions, and the voting system provide a way to indicate those opinions. Like all things evolving few data points, it is subject to fluctuations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `self.session.post` directly, use a function that refactors the post/repost process. There's no need for a decorator here.

```
class Foo:
    def get_token(self) -> str:
        # same as before
        ...

    def _post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        r = self.session.post(*args, **kwargs)
        if r.status_code == 401:
            self.session.headers.update({"X-AUTH-TOKEN": self.get_token()})
            r = self.session.post(*args, **kwargs)
        return r
    
    def get_device(self, ip: str) -> dict[str, Any]:
        data = dumps({"ipAddress": ip.strip()})
    
        r = self._post(BASE_URL + "devices/filter", data=data)
    
        if not r.ok:
            raise Exception()
        elif "content" not in (response := r.json()):
            raise Exception()
    
        return response["content"][0]
```

Comment: Freaking Genius. What a great idea. Thanks alot I'm gonna implement this now!

Comment: Just to add, a decorator would be useful if you wanted to wrap the entire *body* of `get_device` in some code. Here, it's just a portion that you want to wrap, so an explicit wrapper is defined. (Note that if you already *had* a wrapper around `self.session.post`, then it could make sense to define a retry-with-new-token decorator to use with your wrapper.)

Comment: that makes alot of sense especially from what I've seen in Django and how it uses decorators. It's just as you explained.

Really a decorator would make sense on the post function since the decorator wraps all the code within a function.

Thank you fro the explanation